# Firefox 13.0.1 locked me out of session

Tags: php, macos, session, firefox, authentication

(Keep in mind this is on OSX Snow Leopard)

I don't know how to describe this bizarre issue very well or even if this is the right place to do so, but out of nowhere Firefox locked me out of a login session on a dev site on my localhost.  I was saving some data and I was redirected to the login page.  I tried to login and it failed...and failed...and failed some more.

I checked the login PHP script and it reports a match for the username and password, but for some reason I can't actually *log in*.  I feel as though the session is being automatically deleted right after it gets created.  I tried restarting the browser, then my computer.  Nothing.  I downgraded back to Firefox 12, no cigar.  I tried clearing my cache and cookies, same thing.

I attempted to login with Safari and it was *successful*!  Same with Chrome.  So the problem is clearly Firefox.  Could it be that my Firefox installation was corrupted and that simply installing *over* it with an older version won't do anything?  That I'll have to completely remove it and then install it?  I am seriously at my wit's end here.

---

**UPDATE:**

After creating a new Firefox profile in Firefox 12 I was able to login (but only with the *new* profile).  I then re-updated to Firefox 13 and was also able to successfully login (again, only with the *new* profile).

It then occurred to me that there must be something wrong with the *domain* (within the Firefox profile data I'm assuming).  I created a domain **alias** and used *that* to login using the corrupted profile and it worked!  So, I've narrowed it down to the domain and the profile.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: Did you check if the response headers contained the appropriate `Set-Cookie` header

Comment: Try with a fresh firefox profile (run firefox from terminal with "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P" command and create new profile)

Comment: @Rafael Will that remove any of my stored stuff such as bookmarks and addons and so forth?

Comment: @Esailija I just checked the headers using HTTPfox and found Set-Cookie appropriately set in the response headers. I also found "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT" but that was always there.

Comment: all bookmarks and addons are bound to a firefox profile, so when you create a new profile, it won't delete the old one, it will just create a new, fresh profile, with new settings, without addons, empty bookmarks, etc. You can always use the profile manager to switch between existing profiles and manage them.

Comment: @mmmshuddup A browser shouldn't set a cookie that has expired. See description of the "third cookie" here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age If you check your cookies after the response, do you see it being set anywhere?

Comment: @Esailija Ok but why does it work in all other browsers?  Also, it works on my server which is using the exact same code, just doesn't work on my localhost (out of _nowhere_).

Comment: @mmmshuddup I don't know tbh, but if you can see whether firefox actually sets the cookie (`options->options->privacy->remove individual cookies->search for the session cookie`) maybe that helps narrowing down where the problem could be.

Comment: @Rafael I just created a new profile and it worked!  So the question is: what's wrong with the default profile and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you clear "all  cookies" or just "cookies for domain". Sometimes that last option just doesn't cut it - if in doubt clear all cookies.

Comment: since your in development maybe you stored a messed up cookie when testing with firefox, and then fixed the issue before you tested in other browsers or something of the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've narrowed it down to having something to do with your profile, try removing items from your problematic profile one at a time, to pin-point the problematic/corrupted file in the profile.

Since you're on a MAC, your profile should be in one of these two locations:

~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/

~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/

(Source: [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox))

Here are some other links that may prove useful:

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Standard_diagnostic_%28Firefox%29
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_backup

Comment: Looks like the permissions.sqlite was the culprit.  Deleting that file solved the issue and it seems to not have removed any of my settings or anything either. Thanks!