# Firefox does not attempt to load a webpage

Tags: php, apache, firefox

Firefox version 16.0.2 - when I try to visit `http://127.0.0.1/` or `localhost`, it just stops. It stays on the current page and does not attempt to load it. Wget and Chrome works fine.

By not attempting, I mean it's like if I never pressed enter. The address bar changes, but the title or content doesn't. It's like it stops instantly.

Other php files work fine. No rewrite rules active.

Comment: "Other php files work fine." Maybe that specific file is the problem. If you show some code maybe the problem will be clear.

Comment: Did you try clearing firefox cache?

Comment: Im on osx10.8, just updated to 16.0.2 but not seeing this happening. Maybe specify the port `localhost:80`? or check your /etc/hosts, and try accessing via an alias? hmmm or a restart :)

Comment: Do you see the accesss attempt in the server log?

Comment: What does Firebug show in the Network tab?

Comment: I used to have this very problem with some version of firefox. It wasn't just localhost. A lot of sites, firefox would just give up. Being pissed, switched to chrome. Happily ever after.

Comment: Ever considered to remove all plugins and try again? Perhaps some add-on is in your way? Sounds a lot like an add-blocker or similar. Just start with a fresh Firefox profile.

Comment: @hakre is right about the profile.  I never even _knew_ about making new "profiles" until I had weird issues with FF a few months ago.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128353/firefox-13-0-1-locked-me-out-of-session

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a problem with Firefox. I've disabled all addons and plugins, but the same problem was occuring. After deleting my profile and starting over from a clean state, firefox is now loading `http://localhost/`!

Answer (score 0):

clear you firefox browser data/cache